# Test a list in jhipster

Tags: junit, jhipster

Below indicates the ListResourceInt.java file method.

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testList() {
    List<Integer> actual = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    List<Integer> expected = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
}
```

But it will generate following error. 
"error: cannot find symbol" symbol:   method is(List)

I am using gradle and jhipsterVersion: 4.8.2

[Build.gradle dependencies as this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWpj3.png)

How to resolve it? 
Solved the problem by changing to assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);

[error logs as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o1Ch.png)

Comment: are you using some fraemwork like maven etc? and what version of jhipster are you using?

Comment: gradle and jhipsterVersion: 4.8.2

Comment: I have edited the post with your need @nullpointer

Comment: I missed to import "import org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;" But then after added display an error on it cannot find is

Comment: Are you sure of using `junit 4.8.2`?

Comment: Jhipster version is that. but how to know junit version?

Comment: Could you update the question with you `build.gradle`'s  `dependencies` in that case.

Comment: Could you add detailed logs  if it fails to compile after adding junit dependency as well?

Comment: Solved the problem by changing to assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);

Comment: With the same imports? Strange

Comment: yes. Thanks @nullpointer

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fix this using the following in gradle

```
dependencies {
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
}
```

or as stated in the docs about [JUnit `4.10` and before.](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Use-with-Gradle#junit-410-and-earlier)

which could provide you the static import for `is` and the code shall work as follows:-

```
@org.junit.Test
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
public void testList() {
    java.util.List<Integer> actual = java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    java.util.List<Integer> expected = java.util.Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    org.junit.Assert.assertThat(actual, org.hamcrest.core.Is.is(expected));
}
```

***Note***:- I've intentionally used fully qualified names to make sure they are not confused with other and these can be updated accordingly in your code.

Comment: still same error appears even I added the version for junit.

Comment: @R.Zoom Could you add the complete logs in that case of when you face such error during compilation.

Comment: I have edited the post with it now. But may be not easy to see. @nullpointer